# Making form's onsubmit to work only for particular submits

Tags: javascript, php

In PHP program, I have JS function which validates submit `<form ...onsubmit='return isOK();'>`. It works OK. The problem is I want it to work only for particular submits, not for all. Is there any way inside the JS function to find out which submit was pressed, or some PHP trick

Comment: What do you mean by particular submits? Different Forms? Just dont add the function to the form then. Otherwise add a specific class or data- ... and check for the value in yoru submit function

Comment: Provide your code with your different submit first. Then, I think you can perform this by using their `Id` and `switch`ing on the `Id` value for example.

Comment: I have, e.g. two submit buttons on the same form, loginButton and HelpButton. If I press loginButton, then isOK() validation function is called. When I press HelpButton, no validation is needed

Comment: check the value of `submit` button in `isOK()` function.and also in the `PHP` program.

Comment: Is it sth like `if (document.getElementById("submit1").value != "") {...}` ?

Comment: No, the value of `submit1` will not change by clicking on it. you should add `onclick="checkme(this.value)"` for each submit button and check the passed value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
instead of onsubmit u can use onClick.

<input type="submit" onclick="return pressSubmit1()" value="submit1" />

<input type="submit" onclick="return pressSubmit2()" value="submit2" />
```

Comment: onClick is used by another JS function()!

Comment: Yeah, different onclicks instead of single onsubmit seems to be the only way. Gotta rewrite my JS code!

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
    ...
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="check me" onclick="submitform('check')" />
    <input name="submit" type="button" value="do not check me" onclick="submitform('not check')"/>
</form>
```

in javascript:

```
 function submitform(check)
 {
    if(check=='check') checkfrom();

 }
```

in `PHP`

```
if($_POST['submit']=="check me")
 checkform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="allowed" onsubmit='return isOK();'>
----

function isOK() {
    if($(this).hasClass('allowed')) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear, are you using a single submit button or different ones. If you're using different submit buttons then ofcourse you can make checks based on the id of the submit button. On the other hand if is a single submit button then it depends on what the conditions are for submitting or not submitting

Comment: all submits are on the same form. Validation is needed only for particular submits. Other submits must work without validation. onclick() is already used by another JS function

Comment: Is it sth like `if (document.getElementById("submit1").value != "") {...}` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better you write some HTML and Java Script code which you are using. So, it's easy to correct mistake is you have made somewhere in code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

We can check which submit button is clicked, using PHP.
In the PHP page corresponding to the form submit, write

if(extract($_POST) && isset($submitbtn1)) {

```
// some validation for first submit button
```

}
elseif(extract($_POST) && isset($submitbtn2)) {

```
// some validation for second submit button
```

}

Note: we can use $ followed by submit button name inside the extract function. ie. $submitbtn1 is same as $_POST['submitbtn1']

Answer (score 0):

Yes different onclick looks fine as mentioned in the accepted answer. But in the event handler you should have the 
code as below. Note the preventDefault. 
Also since submit is A button that submits the form. You can use button type instead of submit type and then there is no need for preventDefault. Here is the link of the code http://jsbin.com/wikose/4/

```
  function testlogin(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var test = 'not validated';
      if(test === "validated")
      alert("not valid login");
      else
        $('form').submit();
      return false;
    }
```